# .htaccess redirect subfolders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im struggling with a .htaccess settings to get following:
To create Multi-language functionality in my CMS without duplicating the productdatabase I would like to get the content of the default language, but keeping the right url in the addressbar.

For example:

- http://www.myshop.com/en/webshop get the content of http://www.myshop.com/webshop
- http://www.myshop.com/en/collection get the content of http://www.myshop.com/collectie

And also for the products:

- http://www.myshop.com/en/webshop/item1 get content of http://www.myshop.com/webshop/item1
- http://www.myshop.com/en/collection/product1 get the content of http://www.myshop.com/collectie/product1

In short:
In case of calling the folders '/en/webshop/' and '/en/collection/' there must be a rewrite to '/webshop' and '/collectie'.
Anyone got a clue?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Use below rule:-

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/en/(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?en/webshop/(.*)$  /webshop/$1
RewriteRule ^/?en/collection/(.*)$  /collectie/$1
```

- The first line just enables `mod_rewrite`
- The second line (1st rule) matches anything under `/en/webshop` and discards the `/en`
- The third line is similar to the second but it also "renames" `collection` to `collectie`

If you have more folders/paths you want to redirect I 'd suggest adding the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?en/(.*)$  /$1
```

which is rewriting anything that starts with `/en`.

Hope it helps, note it is not tested